# How do I count the amount of non-blank cells in a row, including only cells that are in a column that contains a specific value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

Here is my example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xxmTnRTaA0DPAyibbiXK00YPqhwT5NXH8kf8PtBh0jg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

I am trying to create a formula for the column "Total" that would contain the total amount of non-blank cells for that row, counting only cells that are in a column that contains the value "B". (0 counts as non-blank)

Finding the sum of these columns is actually pretty easy, using this formula (for row 2 as an example):
`=SUMIF($1:$1,"B",2:2)`

For counting non-blank cells however, I couldn't find a similarly simple way to do it. I tried approaching this by using `FILTER` and `COUNTIF`, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**To include zeros** you could use this simple formula and drag it down to as many rows as you like.

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:2,"<>",$C$1:$1,"=B")
```

On the other hand, if you want **to exclude zeros** try:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:2,">0",$C$1:$1,"=B")
```

Function used:  **[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en-GB)**

Answer (score 0):

This formula can do the job :

```
=count(ArrayFormula(IF($C$1:$J$1="B",C2:J2,)))
```

1. `IF + arrayformula` to catch cells within `B` columns
2. `Count()` to count numeric values

[image]

---

[Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-cnhN3q7ztLmH26jAccvP3xaSKGZIKYuIhvcfZ-9zvo/edit?usp=sharing)